# Mysql constraint violation

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

When I use my Zend project on my other MySQL db it is working like a charm. But when I export the database and put it on my other server the same project gives the following error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`devel`.`Service`, CONSTRAINT `Service_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerId`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customerId`))
```

Does anybody know what this is about?

Answer (score 0):

The value you want to insert/update on the table, value of `customerId` is missing from the master `customer` table

Do a select to see if the value exists. Where 100 is a placeholder value.

```
select customerId from customer where customerId = 100;
```

You need to create the `customerId` value first in the customer table.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like someone forgot to disable [foreign key checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) in the export (`mysqldump` would normally include them by default).

If the data is OK on the server, you can use `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` before the import to temporarily disable the check.

Normal use from the MySQL command line would be:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SOURCE /path/to/sql/dump.sql;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting the database completely with table definitions? Maybe the foreign key definition is not present in the other database. Or maybe a datatype is too small. If you defined customerId say as tinyint and the value get larger than 255 the value starts by one again. If the child row looks for that number if won't find it because of this truncation.

Try to find of at which line in your script the error occurs, and try to find if if the customerId value which it tries to insert already exist.

The most important thing is that the data for the parent table is inserted first, then the data for the child tables of the foreign key! Some tools get this order wrong when exporting data to a sql script.